# Factor analysis for categorical data

Tags: categorical-data, factor-analysis, dimensionality-reduction, scale-construction

I was wondering if some of you, experts can provide me advise on my data analysis. I have created a scale with categorical data (options with individual values rather than rating/likert scale or ordinal data). It is a 40 items scale with 7 options to choose from. Respondents will basically choose one amongst the 7 options. The scale asks respondents among the seven motivations (7 options) best describes their motivation across different social situations (40 different social situaions making it 40-item scale).

Sorry if my explanation is abit vague.

However, I hope I can received some help from you.

Comment: Dimensionality reduction technique for nominal variables is called (Multiple) Correspondence Analysis.

Comment: Thank you very much. However, do you have any resources as how to do this on SPSS. I have tried looking but it is usually correspondence analysis rather than multiple? Thanks again

Comment: "Simple" CA is for two categorical variables (i.e. 2d contingency table). "Multiple" CA is for any number of cat. variables. In SPSS, find the latter in Optimal Scaling menu item.